# Why do we plot the standard error of the mean as both positive and negative?

Tags: confidence-interval, mean, standard-error

When we plot the mean of a variable on a scatter plot or a bar plot, why do we plot the standard error of the mean in both directions: positive and negative?

Comment: Note that a standard error only gives about $68\%$ coverage for normally distributed variables. It might be better to plot a $95\%$ confidence interval.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your estimated mean might differ from the true mean in either direction: it can be too high or it can be too low.

If you estimate the mean from your sample to be (e.g.) 3 and you also know that standard error (loosely speaking the average deviation of the estimate from the true mean) is 2 then you expect that your estimate might be off by about 2 in either direction.

In such a case when you see your estimate as "3" there is a reasonable chance it was "1" (as 3 is within a standard error of 1) and as high as "5" (as 3 is within a standard error of 5).

Comment: Standard error and standard deviation are not the same, the former is the latter divided by the square root of N. Standard error is not how much on average we expect to be off. It is the range within which we reasonably expect to estimate the mean from a new random sampling keeping all experimental parameters constant.

Comment: @ReneBt Thank you for the comment, but did you find something in my answer that suggested otherwise? I don't think I confused standard error and standard deviation in the answer.

Comment: If I make certain assumptions I can read it as standard error  correctly, but they are not explicitly made. It would be less ambiguous if you clarified it was the estimate based on averaging N repetitions. The main problem however is you description of it as the average amount your error will be out. The average error, by definition is 0.the mean absolute error will be closer to 0 than the standard error. I can't vote this answer up with something this wrong in it.

Comment: @ReneBt I think the problem you have mainly is the "average" word. Note that I didn't say "mean" there - because I wanted to use that word loosely. Which I felt sufficed for the simple question that was asked. I do agree with you that it might confuse somebody if they took it literally as "mean absolute difference from the true mean". Will see if I can change the wording to reinforce the point that it's only "speaking loosely".